# Do military tactical transport flights provide seatbelts for all occupants?

Tags: safety, military, helicopter, passenger

In several movies I have watched recently, the temporary bench style seats of tactical transport aircraft such as the C-130 do not show seat-belts. I would not be surprised that some instances of seat belts would be ignored during times of war but let's limit this question to standard operations.

***So, is it standard practice for transport aircraft such as the C-130 or Chinook helicopter during large personnel missions to provide all occupants with seat belts?***

Answer (score 6):

Every one I've been on has had them going back to the 70's. Here's a picture that clearly shows them:

[image: C-130 interior]

Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lockheed_Hercules_interior.jpg)